# How to rewrite slug of custom post type archive page

Tags: slug, custom-post-type-archives

I have a CPT called "case-studies" and the slug of the archive page of this CPT is `www.my-domain.com/case-studies` and the slug of the CPT posts is `www.my-domain.com/case-studies/case-study-name`.

Now, for SEO purposes, I have to change the slug of the archive page to "testimonials-case-studies" so the slug for the "case-studies" archive page it has to be `www.my-domain.com/testimonials-case-studies/` and the slug for the posts have to be `www.my-domain.com/case-studies/case-study-name` (same as before).

What is the best way or the solution for this?

What I have tried so far is:

- creating a custom page template and change the slug of the page to `/testimonials-case-studies/` and redirect `/case-studies/` to `/testimonials-case-studies/` but the posts `www.my-domain.com/case-studies/case-study-name` are not working because there is a problem with redirection.
- Using:

  ```php
  'rewrite' => array(
      'slug' => 'testimonials-case-studies',
      'with_front' => false
  ),
  ```

In the custom post type BUT the slug for the post change to `www.my-domain.com/testimonials-case-studies/case-study-name` but IT HAS to be: `www.my-domain.com/case-studies/case-study-name`

Is there a possible solution for this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pass the desired archive slug via `has_archive`:

```
$args = array(
    'rewrite'     => array( 'slug' => 'case-studies' ),
    'has_archive' => 'testimonials-case-studies',
);
```

Comment: You may also need to `unregister_post_type()` right before re-registering it, to get WP to accept the change.

Comment: Yeap! Thanks a lot! https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#has_archive